# Must all details match exactly if receiving payment via my personal bank account?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, online-payment, electronic-payment

I want to use my personal bank account to receive payment for my work e.g. as a first-time software developer. I found a company who wants to list my application for sale in their online store. To receive payment for each sale, I must provide the company with my name, my bank account number and the routing number of my bank account.

This is my question: Must my first name and surname exactly match the information that my bank has on record for my account?

Comment: Why does the company know your bank account number and routing number of the bank? Did you give it to them because they want to pay your salary by direct deposit into the account? Or make an automated withdrawal (e.g. mortgage payment, utility bill, credit-card bill) that _you_ have authorized them to make from your bank account? Or do your preprinted checks not have your name and address on them, just the bank account number and routing number, and you are worried that the company (whom you paid by such a check) will find out your name etc?

Comment: Can you also add the country tag. The Banking regulations vary from country to country

Comment: I suspect that the OP is interested to know if he can give someone else's account as his own and get caught easily. Vote to close.

Comment: @littleadv or maybe OP is a nigerian prince and looking for the best way to prove to people that he is really a nigerian prince.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate i will be get payed by them and i don't want  to share my full name with them. I can provide more detail if it is necessary.

Comment: @Dheer i have added the country tag.

Comment: @user65721 Yes indeed, you should provide more details. You want a company to pay you without them knowing what your name is, just your account number. Sounds like a fraudulent transaction, possibly on both sides. I too vote to close.

Comment: I am an indie android dev and google does not provide app selling in my country. So i have opened my dev account as US account. I don't have a US bank account and i am planning to use my friend's bank account to get payed from google. Google asks bank account number and routing number to pay your earnings. What i am asking is should i change my name to my friend's name in the google dev account or providing his bank account details would be enough? Also can google check if the dev account name and bank account name matches. I want to know it beforehand to avoid future conflicts.

Comment: @user65721 Thank you for explaining your rationale. That helps a lot! I rephrased your question. I hope is a better reflection of what you need to know.

Comment: @DilipSarwate : the OP didn't need to explain himself, nothing he was doing would have stopped law enforcement if they needed to investigate a bank account "with no name", this is only a limitation for private companies finding out information, which is what the question was about. its kind of alarming that there were several votes to close using the poor consensus that this was a question about something fraudulent. An example of democracy without qualifications.

Comment: @CQM A company paying money to an individual known only as user65721 could be paying for services rendered or goods delivered etc. Not revealing the name of the payee to the company, only a bank account number, opens up the possibility of a later fraudulent claim of nonpayment. If the coyness about the name on the account was because the payer was a "Nigerian bank" scammer who would drain the account once he knew both the name and the account number, the fraud would be at the other end. In either case, the OP *did* need to provide more explanation than he had in his original question.

Comment: @CQM Also, I take offense at your characterization of the votes to close as democracy without qualifications. People *did* ask for details and received flippant answers about Nigerian princes.

Comment: @CQM it is in fact something fraudulent. The OP may not be aware of it, but he's most likely committing tax fraud, to begin with.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate if you know how to read you can see that, that responde was to a stupid accusation and also OP delevired the details when people asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bank account and routing number does not reveal this information on its own.

A private company would therefore not be able to legally access the information about the name of the account holder. Law enforcement would still be able to get this information, if ever needed.

You can have money deposited into any account that you know the # and routing number of. You could also walk up to a bank teller with a wad of cash and tell them just the # and the routing number, if that account is with their bank. It will go to the right place.

Comment: I doubt that you can go to a bank teller and deposit a wad of cash into an account for which you provide only a bank account number _in that bank_, and even more so if you want to deposit the money into a bank account in a _different_ bank.  Have you tried this yourself and know it works?

Comment: uh yes, I have. I saw you got upvoted, do people really just not understand how the banking system works and what services it provides? This is a problem for the person making the deposit, since the teller is not inclined to tell you who's account it is, for instance, if you aren't sure.

Comment: I understand how the banking system works. You said "You could also walk up to a bank teller with a wad of cash and tell them just the # and the routing number" Yes, the teller will not reveal the name on the account, and so the OP, as the putative recipient, will not have his name revealed to the depositor during this transaction. But I suggest that the transaction will likely be aborted because the teller will refuse to accept the deposit. A company making a payment will send someone to a bank with a wad of cash? The company will not want to know whom it is paying? Just user65721 will do?

Comment: the teller will not refuse to accept the deposit.

Comment: @DilipSarwate is correct, based on my personal experience with banks in the U.S.A. While yes, it would *seem* as though a bank would not hesitate to accept a deposit, and in fact, that was the case 15+ years ago, it is not true now. Often, to accept a deposit, the teller wants a completed deposit slip (with routing #, account # and name) or in lieu of that, photo ID and an active/ valid check guarantee card (or debit card) at that bank.

Comment: Why people down voting the only answer. Is his answer is not correct? The basic question is can a company find out your name from your bank account number and routing number. And answers says no, they can't. However the discussion on the comments are not related to real question. If you think he is wrong about it please explain why he is wrong.

Comment: @FeralOink I edited with some information

Comment: @user65721 The answer is not correct. Also, what you're planning to do will get your friend in trouble with the IRS. I'd advise him not to allow you using his account for money laundering (that is, in essence, what you're going to do). There's a reason why Google doesn't want to transfer money to your country, and the reason is *taxes*. By working around that you're likely to be breaking the US tax law (unless your friend opens a business and buys software from you and sells it to Google, then the tax problem shifts from Google to your friend).

Comment: @user65721 in the USA, money laundering `requires` an illegal `ORIGIN`, and the burden of proof is on the government to find that illegal origin. Just because the origin is obfuscated does not make the origin illicit, and as I have stated, due to the nature of ACH and Wire transfers, the entire transaction will have a trail for law enforcement to follow IF NEED BE (ie. if anything illegal actually happened), but private companies will not be able to get this information..usually..which is what was asked. Using your friend's bank account comes with its own pros & cons but no it is not illegal.